# Problem displaying QGraphicsGeoMap

Tags: qt, dictionary, qt-creator, ovi

I'm new to Qt, and I'm trying to display the Ovi map.

Unfortunately, my program just crashes. Here is my code:

```
    MapView::MapView(QWidget *parent, const char *name) {

    mappingManager = 0;


    QGeoServiceProvider *serviceProvider = new QGeoServiceProvider("nokia");
    // QGeoSearchManager *searchManager = 0;
    // QGeoServiceProvider serviceProvider("nokia");
    //QGeoRoutingManager *routingManager = 0;
    //routingManager = serviceProvider.routingManager();

    if (serviceProvider->error() == QGeoServiceProvider::NoError) {
        mappingManager = serviceProvider->mappingManager();
       // searchManager = serviceProvider.searchManager();

        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene, this);
        mapGraphics = new QGraphicsGeoMap(mappingManager);
        mapGraphics->setMapType(QGraphicsGeoMap::StreetMap);
        mapGraphics->setConnectivityMode(QGraphicsGeoMap::HybridMode);
       // scene->addText("Map view");
        scene->addItem(mapGraphics);

        view->show();
    } else {
       QMessageBox::information(this, "Map", "Service provider error");
    }
}
```

I've commented out the line which I think is causing the crash - the scene->addItem(mapGraphics);

How should I add the mapGraphics so I can see it on screen?
I'd really appreciate a hand with this.

Thankyou in advance, J

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Maps Demo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/tutorials-mapsdemo.html) tutorial.

The source code is found in {QtSDK}\Examples\4.7\mobile\mapsdemo\ or on [qt.gitorious.org](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility/qt-mobility/trees/master/examples/mapsdemo)